# How to dynamically select between variable groups when running an Azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have a pipeline that we want to run with different configurations. So we have defined a set of variable groups like

- Config Prefix - Config 1
- Config Prefix - Config 2
- Config Prefix - Config 3

Each group define the same variables with different values. And then we reference them in the pipeline:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: configName
  displayName: Configuration
  type: string
  values:
  - 'Config 1'
  - 'Config 2'
  - 'Config 3'

variables:
- group: "Config Prefix - ${{ parameters.configName }}"

steps:
- script: |
    echo "--------------------------------"
    echo "Use config for ${{ parameters.configName }}"
    echo "--------------------------------"
    echo "var1: '$(var1)'"
    echo "var2: '$(var2)'"
    echo "var3: '$(var3)'"
    echo "--------------------------------"
```

On running the pipeline we can select configuration and run. But in order to add a new configuration we must add the new variable group and then modify the pipeline.

Would it be possible to have the pipeline dynamically present the available configurations without hard coding them? Eg if we could define the list of groups somewhere or just have the pipeline find all groups with the prefix

Comment: I would ask as to what the end goal of this configuration is. There are ways to dynamically build and load variable groups based on the name using other values like the environment name. Are you attempting to use groups tied to environments or a suite of applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**, [it's impossible](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-make-values-dynamic-for-parameters/975368) in Azure Pipelines.

You can do an automation that check your variable groups each X time, if a new group with your prefix added the automation will edit the yaml.